# Calling a variable after underscore in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: command-line

In my batch file I am trying to call a variable after underscore. But the variable is not getting recognized if added after an underscore.

```
set /p X=Folder name:%=%
mkdir Delta_%X%
```

So windows was creating a directory with name Delta_ instead of Delta_{Folder name user provided for X} for the above code.

To work around this situation I assigned underscore to another variable and called both the variables and it works fine. Wanted to check if there is another(correct) way to handle this issue.

Workaround:

```
set /p X=Folder name:%=%
set Z=_
mkdir Delta%Z%%X%
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying do do? Another way to handle what exactly? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Edited my question :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with adding an underscore using either method you describe.  However, you could also add an underscore to your `%X%` variable like this:

```
set /p X=Folder name: 
set X=_%X%
```

or you could add Delta_ like this:

```
set X=Delta_%X%
```

Of course, you may not want to do this if you need to preserve the actual user input for later.  If that's the case, you can do this instead:

```
set /p X=Folder name: 
set Y=Delta_%X%
echo user entered: %X%
mkdir %Y%
```

Comment: Edited my question :)